# Debugging a Perl program: Hashes, Writing to and Accessing Filehandles

Tags: perl, debugging, hash, bioinformatics, filehandle

I'm working on a bioinformatics project that involves piping together different scripts and input parameters for the analysis of Next-Gen Sequencing Illumina data. I need help debugging the first script. It's task is to parse a qseq file, convert the 'good' samples to fastq format, and save the output to temporary txt files (to disk).

For purposes of debugging, the piping scheme goes like this:

```
# the input parameters are "fed" into the script and the output is written
# to tmp.txt
script01.pl [input parameters] > tmp.txt
```

I type this  command into the terminal then look in the tmp.txt file to check if the script outputs the expected results. But for the overall project I have something called a wrapper script that pipes all the scripts together. Script01 will save the output to tmp files for end1 and end2 data since they need to be processed by scripts 02-06 separately.

Here's the the code. I added descriptive comments so you can understand what's going on. Also, I don't have the qseq file to show you but just assume that I'm parsing the fields correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $end1_temp=shift; # this variable is the location of the temporary file
my $end2_temp=shift; # this variable is the location of the temporary file
my $qseq_file=shift;
my $barcode=shift;

# declare and initialize variables
my $overhang= 'C[AT]GC';
my $end1_trim_offset= length($barcode)+4;
my $end2_trim_offset= 4; 

my %to_keep=(); # an empty hash
my @line=();    # an empty array

# open the qseq file, or exit
open (QSEQ_1_FILE, $qseq_file) or die "couldn't open $qseq_file for read\n";

# also, open (for output) the end1 temp file, so we can write to it while
# we process the end1 input file above
(open END_1_FILEOUT,">$end1_temp") or die "couldn't open $end1_temp for write\n";

# reads each line of the qseq data file one at a time. 
# assume each sample is kept on a separate line
while(<QSEQ_1_FILE>){
chomp; @line=split; # index and formats the qseq fields for parsing

# skip samples those that didn't pass QC
$line[10]>0 or next;

# process the samples here. look at only the samples that pass the quality 
# control and whose sequences contain the barcode+overhang at the beginning
# of the string, otherwise skip to the next sample in the data file 
# (i.e start the next iteration of the loop)

# trim the barcode+overhang from seq and qual
$line[8]= substr($line[8], $end1_trim_offset); #sequence
$line[9]= substr($line[9], $end1_trim_offset); #quality

# unique sequence identifier. don't worry about what $line[1-6] represent
# just know that $identifier is unique for each of the 'good' samples
my $identifier = $line[0].'-'.$line[1].'-'.$line[2].'_'.$line[3].'-'.$line[4].'-'.$line[5].'_#'.$line[6];

# store the identifiers of the 'good' samples in a hash.
# the hash should contain the identifier as the key and numbers (1,2,3,etc.)
# as the values. the following increments the hash values for each identifier.
$to_keep{$identifier}++;

# the following below is suppose to write information to the filehandle in fastq format:
# @[the identifier]/1
# sequence [ATGCAGTAAT...]
# +[the identifier]/1
# quality [ASCII characters]

print END_1_FILEOUT '@' . "$identifier/1\n$line[8]\n" . '+' . identifier/1\n$line[9]\n";

}
print "Found " . int(keys %to_keep) . " reads from end1\n";
# close the filehandles
close QSEQ_FILE; close END_1_FILEOUT;
```

At this point, I have a hash containing the identifiers of only the 'good' sequences and have written the fastq data to a stored location. Script01 is suppose to save the fastq output to temp files on disk.

`$end1_temp = '~/tmp/sampleD1_end1.fq'` and `end2_temp = '~/tmp/sampleD1_end2.fq'`

Question: Is the `print END_1_FILE` line above writing the fastq data to the filehandle or is it writing to the $end1_temp variable? I ask because I'm going to need to pass the $end1_temp and the $end2_temp variables to script02. Also, for purposes of debugging how do I view the fastq output from script01?

Here's the rest of the code that I need help with. It's on the same script and directly follows the code above:

```
# if the sequence is paired (has both end1 and end2 data), then the qseq_2 file exists and the conditions evaluates to true
if ($end2_temp) {
# changes the qseq filename from file name from end1 to end2 data
# don't worry about why it works
$qseq_file=~ s/'_1_'/'_2_'/;

open (QSEQ_2_FILE, $qseq_file) or die "could not open $qseq_file for read\n";

# open (for output) the end2 temp file, so we can write to it while we process
# the end2 input file above
open (END_2_FILEOUT, ">$end2_temp") or die "could not open $end2_temp for write\n";

# reads each line of the end2 file one at a time
while(<QSEQ_2_FILE>){
# skip comments
/^\#/ and next;

chomp; #keep the qseq fields on one line.
my @line= split; #indexes the qseq fields.

# unique sequence identifier that preserves the sequencing information
# in other words, samples from end1 and end2 will have the same unique
# identifier because they contain the exact same fields in columns 0-6 
# or $line[0-6]. also end1 and end2 have the same number of samples
my $identifier = $line[0] .'-'.$line[1].'-'.$line[2].'_'.$line[3].'-'.$line[4].'-'.$line[5].'_#'.$line[6];

# recall the %to_keep hash which stored the identifiers of the 'good' samples; 
# it was inside the QSEQ_1_FILE loop
# here I only want the end2 samples whose identifiers match the identifiers
# from the end1 samples
# skip sample where end1 didn't pass; does this work??
# the condition is suppose to evaluate to false if the identifiers don't match
$to_keep{$identifier} or next;

# trim the barcode+overhang from seq and qual
$line[8]=substr($line[8], $end2_trim_offset);  # sequence
$line[9]=substr($line[9], $end2_trim_offset);  # quality

print END_2_FILEOUT '@' . "$identifier/2\n$line[8]\n" . '+' . "$identifier/2\n$line[9]\n";

}

close QSEQ_2_FILE; close END_2_FILEOUT;

}
```

This is the end of script01. At this point, I should have written the fastq data of 'good' samples for end1 and end2 to separate stored locations. Script01 is suppose to save the fastq output to two temp files on disk. I guess my question is for purposes of debugging, how do I view the tmp files created by script01?

Lastly, when I enter the command `script01.pl [input parameters] > tmp.txt` into the Linux terminal, it saves the output of script01 to tmp.txt. "Found X reads from end1" is what the script prints after processing the end1 reads, where X is the number of reads in the %to_keep hash.

When I look in tmp.txt, it displays `Found 0 reads from end1.` Since it prints 0, it means there is nothing stored in the hash. It's suppose to store around 6.3 million reads from end1. Can someone help me figure out why none of the reads are getting stored in the hash?

I think the problem is none of the reads are passing the the criteria I'm using for deciding whether or not they should be stored in hash. Another problem might be with how I'm storing the identifiers.

Can you guys look over it and see if there's anything I might have missed?

thanks. any suggestions or answers to my questions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you provided does not compile.

Comment: I have the code saved in my directory. When I enter `perl -c script01.pl` where script01.pl is the name of the program, the terminal returns `script01.pl syntax OK`. I think it doesn't compile as written above because I didn't write out all the code. There are probably `Use of uninitialized value` or `...requires explicit package name` errors. The code I have saved compiles okay.

Comment: I guess I should edit the code above so that it compiles. That way it's easier for you guys to help me. I didn't write out all the code because then it would be a little too long. Also, to do actual the debugging you need the correct data files saved in your directory and the input parameters to pass to script01. I wrote a lot of general questions you guys can help me on.

Comment: There's no "guessing" about it. We'd be wasting our time with all the errors that exist in what you posted but not in the file you didn't show us. Provide a *runnable*, *minimal* demonstration of the problem. That includes any data needed to produce the error!

Comment: okay I'll to provide a _runnable, minimal_ demonstration of the problem. gimme a minute. in the meantime, can you look at the questions?

Comment: OK, I think the code above should compile now. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: btw, the second block of code immediately follows the first block of code.

Comment: Critical var $trim_offset still missing. Are you saying it's too hard for you to run it?? Then why would we run it, then!! Also, no hint as to what data should be provided. again, **Provide a runnable, minimal demonstration of the problem. That includes any data needed to produce the error! **

Comment: [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) explains it in all detail.

Comment: @cooldood3490 : People appreciate it when you isolate the problem you're dealing with to the smallest possible chunk of code.  It doesn't even have to resemble your original program, as long as the algorithm that's giving you trouble is minimally represented, in a way that will give us the same failure point that you're experiencing.  Then we don't have to sift through a post that consumes three browser-screens to try to figure out what you're asking about.  If you eliminate the distractions, you get better answers.

Comment: First of all, gimme a break. It's almost 3:30am EST. I've been working hard all day, trying to debug the errors. I think it's a bit unfair for people to give me a thumbs down for 'not showing any research effort' TO:ikegami I fixed the error you noted. TO:mugen kenichi thanks for the link. @DavidO thanks for the suggestion. I posted this lengthy code because I have several questions on it but you're right. This question can probably be broken down into 3 separate posts.

Comment: @mugen kenichi and TO:ikegami After I get some sleep, I'll repost the question but isolate the problems into smaller chunks. DavidO's comment is duly noted. I'll be sure to provide the link here to the questions.

Comment: you could also ask biostar: http://www.biostars.org

Comment: @cooldood3490: I realize that you think ikegami's being a hard-ass unnecessarily, but it's not just about making it easier for us to help you. Reducing the problem to a minimal, runnable piece of code and data is itself a very powerful debugging technique. 99% of the questions I intend to ask on SO or similar sites never actually get asked because, in the course of producing a minimal demonstration of them, I find the solution on my own. Doing that doesn't just help us help you, it also helps you to help yourself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions everyone. your tips will help me post better questions in the future.

Comment: I complained about you "not showing us the problem you want us to solve", not "not showing any research effort". (Instead of demonstrating your problem, you posted had *numerous* problems your actual code did not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: Is the print END_1_FILE line above writing the fastq data to
>   the filehandle or is it writing to the $end1_temp variable?

I assume you mean `END_1_FILEOUT`. This is an writeable filehandle to a file whose named is stored in `$end1_temp`. The data will be sent to the file.

> Also, for purposes of debugging how do I view the fastq output from
>   script01?

You look in the file. From your question I think the file is called `~/tmp/sampleD1_end1.fq`. You should look in there.

> Script01 is suppose to save the fastq output to two temp files on
>   disk. I guess my question is for purposes of debugging, how do I view
>   the tmp files created by script01?

As before, the output should be in the files whose names are in `$end1_temp` and `$end2_temp`, presumably `~/tmp/sampleD1_end1.fq` and `~/tmp/sampleD1_end2.fq`. Open them with your editor and take a look.

> Lastly, when I enter the command script01.pl [input parameters] >
>   tmp.txt into the Linux terminal, it saves the output of script01 to
>   tmp.txt. When I look in tmp.txt it displays "Found 0 reads from end1".
>   Since it prints 0, it means there is nothing stored in the hash. It's
>   suppose to store around 6.3 million reads from end1. Can someone help
>   me figure out why none of the reads are getting stored in the hash?

This is basic debugging. From your code it is clear that either the QSeq file you are reading is empty or your test `$line[10] > 0 or next` is throwing out every record. Both are simple to check by adding a diagnostic `print` statement directly after the `split` to show the value of `$line[10]`. My bet is that you are looking at the wrong field.

In addition to this you really should indent your code. That would help us to understand it far better than the extensive comments. Also,

```
$line[10] > 0 or next
```

is better written as

```
next unless $line[10] > 0
```

and you should use the three-parameter form of `open` and lexical filehandles.

Here is a tidied version of your code with these improvements as well as a few more

```
use strict;
use warnings;

die qq(Insufficient arguments "@ARGV") unless @ARGV >= 4;

my ($end1_temp, $end2_temp, $qseq1_file, $barcode) = @ARGV;

my $overhang         = 'C[AT]GC';
my $end1_trim_offset = length($barcode) + 4;
my $end2_trim_offset = 4;

my $idformat = '%s-%s-%s_%s-%s-%s_#%s';

my %to_keep;

open my $qsec1, '<', $qseq1_file
    or die "couldn't open $qseq1_file for read\n";

open my $end1, '>', $end1_temp
    or die "couldn't open $end1_temp for write\n";

while (<$qsec1>) {

  my @line = split;
  next unless $line[10] > 0;

  $_ = substr($_, $end1_trim_offset) for @line[8,9];

  my $identifier = sprintf $idformat, @line;
  $to_keep{$identifier}++;

  print $end1
      '@' . "$identifier/1\n" .
      "$line[8]\n" .
      '+' . "$identifier/1\n" .
      "$line[9]\n";
}

close $qsec1;
close $end1;

printf "Found %d reads from end1\n", int keys %to_keep;


exit unless $end2_temp;

$qseq1_file =~ s/'_1_'/'_2_'/;

open my $qseq2, '<', $qseq1_file
    or die "could not open $qseq1_file for read\n";

open my $end2, '>', $end2_temp
    or die "could not open $end2_temp for write\n";

while (<$qseq2>) {

  next if /^#/;
  my @line = split;

  my $identifier = sprintf $idformat, @line;
  next unless $to_keep{$identifier};

  $_ = substr($_, $end2_trim_offset) for @line[8,9];

  print $end2
      '@' . "$identifier/2\n" .
      "$line[8]\n" .
      '+' . "$identifier/2\n" .
      "$line[9]\n";
}

close $qseq2;
close $end2;
```

Comment: thanks for answering my `END_1_FILEOUT` question. The data _was_ sent to the file. I didn't really understand how writeable filehandles worked but you explained it pretty clear. I figured out where the temp files created by script01 were located and how to open them. Currently there isn't anything being written to them. I added the diagnostic `print` statement right before the `split` to show the value of `$line[10]`. They're all returning values of `0`. you're right, my test `$line[10] > 0 or next;` is throwing out every record.

Comment: I need to figure out why `$line[10]` is return values of 0. There are definitely samples that have a QC field of 1. I have to double check that I'm reading the correct field. I'm currently working through the rest of your suggestions. I'll keep everyone updated.

Comment: I figured it out!! `Found 7776851 reads from end1` Also, both of the temp files created by script01 have the correct fastq format. @Borodin thank you for helping me. I put in several diagnostic `print` statements to debug the errors. there were several of them. I'm going to implement the tidied version you provided. it looks a lot neater compared to mine. Now I get to move onto to debugging scripts 02-06. C'est la vie of a programmer! thanks again